# Preloading multiple backgrounds

Tags: jquery

a nice member helped me preload a css background image, and I thought I would expand on that to preload more background images, however when I tried making a demo I ran into problems.

This is the original:

```
var  src = 'image1.jpg'
  , $img = $( '<img src="' + src + '">' );

$img.bind( 'load', function(){
    $( '#SomeDiv' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src + ')' );
    //more code here



} );
if( $img[0].width ){ $img.trigger( 'load' ); }
```

And this is what I did:

```
var  src1 = 'image1.jpg'
  , $img1 = $( '<img src="' + src1 + '">' );

var  src2 = 'image2.jpg'
  , $img2 = $( '<img src="' + src2 + '">' );

$img1.bind( 'load', function(){
    $( '#SomeDiv' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src1 + ')' );
    //more code here
} );

$img2.bind( 'load', function(){
    $( '#AnotherDiv' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src2 + ')' );
    //more code here
} );


if( $img[0].width ){ $img.trigger( 'load' ); }
```

Here's a 'working' example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/k2Ycv/

Thanks for the help everyone :))

Comment: Check the line at the bottom. ```$img``` no longer exists.

Comment: You're right. I changed it to $img1, however I just noticed that there's an error no matter what I do that `$img1 is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original:

```
if( $img[0].width ){ $img.trigger( 'load' ); }
```

Should be:

```
if( $img1[0].width ){ $img1.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img2[0].width ){ $img2.trigger( 'load' ); }
```

Comment: Thanks Kumu, but I just noticed that I'm getting an error at the beggining of the code, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/k2Ycv/2/.

`$img1 is null`

Comment: So looked at your jsfiddle, you are using moo tools as your framework, change it to jquery and it should work

Comment: Thanks Kumu. That, and the fact that my ID's started with capitals were the problem.. I don't know why, but you can't begin an ID with a capital :/.